# how to compare and tabulate frequency of common elements between two vectors in r

Tags: r, compare, frequency, element

I have two vectors having common and repetitive elements. I want a table comparing the frequency of common elements in both vectors. Here is subset

```
plyr::count(V1)
          x freq
1  A*02:01  106

2  A*02:02   88

3  A*03:01   95

4  A*03:02   60

plyr::count(V2)

   x freq

1  A*02:01   11

2  A*02:02   11

3  A*02:04    1

4  A*03:01   20
```

**The Output I want is:**

```
   x  freq.V1  freq.V2

1  A*02:01    106     11 


2  A*02:02     88     11


3  A*03:01     60     20
```

Comment: ps. should the last row of your output be `A*03:01 95 20`

Answer (score 1):

I think `merge` seems a good choice here as the default is to keep observations common to both datasets. So the following should work

```
merge(plyr::count(V1), plyr::count(V2), by="x")
```

Worked example

```
plyr::count(mtcars$gear)
#   x freq
# 1 3   15
# 2 4   12
# 3 5    5
plyr::count(mtcars$gear[1:10])
#   x freq
# 1 3    4
# 2 4    6

merge(
plyr::count(mtcars$gear),
plyr::count(mtcars$gear[1:10]), 
by="x")
#   x freq.x freq.y
# 1 3     15      4
# 2 4     12      6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `table`:

```
tbl1 <- table(V1[V1 %in% (int <- intersect(unique(V1), unique(V2)))])
tbl2 <- table(V2[V2 %in% int])

data.frame(x = names(tbl1), freq.V1 = as.vector(tbl1), freq.V2 = as.vector(tbl2))
```

Or my favorite, `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(V1 = V1, V2 = V2)

DT[V1 %in% unique(V2), .(freq.V1 = .N), by = .(x = V1)
   ][DT[V2 %in% unique(V1), .N, by = .(x = V2)],
     freq.V2 := i.N, on = "x", nomatch = 0L]
```

Of course both options look much simpler if you know beforehand that `V1` and `V2` consist of the same set of elements:

```
data.frame(x = names(tbl1 <- table(V1)), freq.V1 = as.vector(tbl1),
           freq.V2 = as.vector(table(V2)))
```

and

```
DT[ , .(freq.V1 = .N), by = .(x = V1)
   ][DT[ , .(freq.V2 = .N), by = .(x = V2)], on = "x"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; however I did not get desired results with the first two options. I should have mentioned that the vectors are of different length. Some elements are common to both while others are unique. I think your code is recycling vector of smaller length.

The result I get from your first code somehow show same frequency for both the vectors.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment MichaelChirico, your method is working.